# Connection pooling using custom connection provider

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate, connection-pooling, nhibernate-3

Is connection pooling enabled when you use a custom connection provider that generates connection strings dynamically? The user is the only data changed in the connection string, and many sessions can be opened for the same user through the time. By the way, I'm using NHibernate 3.0 to connect to a database in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how the connection string is generated, the ADO.NET pooling is used, however to bind a connection string to a pool the sting must be identical, so if the user name change this condition is not satisfied, and as a result you will obtain a connection from different pools for each user.